# Unable to send POST request to Node.js HTTP Webserver from anything other than localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, server, axios

I'm currently trying to send text/data from a client browser to a Node.js webserver, but whenever I use anything other than localhost, I receive a "POST ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" error.

Here's the code for the client (html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Client</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="stream" rows="8" cols="80" oninput="update(this.value)"></textarea>
    <script>

      function update(v) {
        let data = {
          text: v
        };
        send(data);
      }

      function send(d) {
        axios.post(
          "http://<the server IP>:34567",
          JSON.stringify(d)
        ).then(res => {
          // do nothing
        }).catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the server code (node.js; http is installed as a node module):

```
const http = require("http");

const port = 34567;

http.createServer(async (req, res) => {

  const headers = {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS, POST, GET",
    "Access-Control-Max-Age": 2592000,
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*"
  };

  switch (req.method) {
    case "GET":
      // Write success header:
      res.writeHead(200, headers);

      // Respond:
      res.write("not yet implemented");
      // Close:
      res.end();
      return;
    break;
    case "POST":

      const buffers = [];

      for await (const chunk of req) {
        buffers.push(chunk);
      }

      const data = Buffer.concat(buffers).toString();

      console.log(JSON.parse(data).text); // Should print the text from the textarea

      res.writeHead(200, headers);
      res.end();
      return;
    break;
    case "OPTIONS":
      res.writeHead(204, headers);
      res.end();
      return;
    break;
  }

  res.writeHead(405, headers);
  res.end(`${req.method} is not allowed for the request.`);

}).listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`[INFO] Server is active on port ${port}.`)
});
```

I've already port-forwarded the 34567 port (TCP).

Whenever I'm on the host computer, and I use "localhost" for the server IP, everything works fine. The text in the client textarea shows up instantly in the server console. However, when I change this to my actual IP (looks something like 12.34.567.890), everything stops working. I'll usually get the "POST ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" error I mentioned earlier, but after a while, the server will (sometimes, not always) receive the data (I'm talking like... almost a minute later, which makes no sense).

What am I doing wrong here?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not checking for routes, you're just checking the http method (post, get, etc..)

The following example does a couple of things..

- Lets you listen for specific routes
- Lets you listen for specific http methods on those specific routes

Imagine you have a folder with two files, `server.js` and `home.html`, as shown below. If you run `node server.js` and then open a browser and go to `localhost:34567/home` and open a browser console. From there, start typing. You should see data being logged client side as well as server side.

The reason this is happening is because browsers are weird. If you don't serve the html file from a server, your browser has security features in place that prevent you from talking to your server (or any server). Basically, the url in your browser can't start with `file://` when you're trying to communicate via XHR (axios/fetch/etc).

## `server.js`

```js
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const fspath = require("path");
const url = require("url");

const server = http.createServer(async (request, response) => {
  const path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
  switch (path) {
    /**
     * @route '/home' description for route
     * @methods (GET)
     */
    case "/home": {
      switch (request.method) {
        case "GET":
        default: {
          try {
            const html = await fs.readFileSync(fspath.resolve("./home.html"));
            response.writeHead(200);
            response.write(html);
          } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
            response.writeHead(500);
            response.write("unable to read home html : " + e);
          }
          response.end();
        }
      }
    }

    /**
     * @route '/update'
     * @methods (POST)
     */
    case "/update": {
      switch (request.method) {
        case "POST": {
          console.log("in /update POST");
          const buffers = [];
          for await (const chunk of request) {
            buffers.push(chunk);
          }
          const data = Buffer.concat(buffers).toString();
          console.log(JSON.parse(data));
          response.end();
        }
        default: {
          response.end();
        }
      }
    }
    default: {
      response.end();
    }
  }
});

server.listen(34567);

const serverAddress = server.address();
const serverIp = serverAddress.address === "::" ? "localhost" : serverAddress.address;

console.log(`Server listening at : ${serverIp}:${serverAddress.port} : go to http://localhost:34567/home`);
```

## `home.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Client</title>
    <!-- script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="stream" rows="8" cols="80" oninput="update(this.value)"></textarea>
    <script>
      async function update(v) {
        let data = {
          text: v,
        };
        await send(data);
      }

      async function send(d) {
        try {
          const res = await fetch("/update", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(d),
          });
          console.log(res);
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
        // ~
        // REMOVED : sorry, fetch was just easier..
        // ~
        // axios.post(
        //   "http://<the server IP>:34567",
        //   JSON.stringify(d)
        // ).then(res => {
        //   // do nothing
        // }).catch(error => {
        //   console.error(error);
        // });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! I've noticed that things don't load properly if you're on the same network as the server (I've noticed this with other servers too, not just this HTTP one)—is there a reason for this? And is there a way to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "things don't load properly"?? I tested that demo and it worked perfectly fine for me. If you are referring to the fact that when you change code, your changes are not reflected until you stop the server and start it again? If so, that is normal. Something like `nodemon` auto-reloads (stops then starts) your server when a file it is watching has changed. It may be something related to the network you're on or the computer you're using (meaning, your company might have your computer locked down?).. Idk - hard to tell you whats wrong when I have no info to go on lol.

Comment: When on the same network as the server (for example when I'm running the server on my PC, and connect to it on my phone using WiFi), the page takes ages to load and usually times me out. When I use data or a different network than the one the server is running on, everything works exactly how it's supposed to. I'm on a home network so things being "locked down" shouldn't be an issue. I'm guessing it has something to do with the way our router is configured?

Comment: Are you browsing to your computers IP address? Instead of "http://localhost:34567/home" are you putting "http://9.9.9.9:34567/home" (where 9.9.9.9 is the IP address of your computer)? Your phone might be forcing https, which won't work. You have to specifically browse to "http" since your server is not setup to use SSL (even then your phone might still try to force SSL/https as a security feature).

Comment: Could also be the firewall on your computer... Do you have port 34567 open to the "outside"?

Comment: I'm using the IP address of my network (it's the same IP on all devices in my house, the one shown on ipchicken.com). I've already port forwarded port 34567, and had a friend confirm that it works elsewhere.